# Query Performance Comparison

Tags: sql-server-2008, query-performance, sql-execution-plan

I'm completely confused between the performance of running time of some 'similar' statements.

```
select * from  DLIFE.IS_TABLE_REPORT where [project_name] = 'myProject'
-- (82 row(s) affected) in 02:10
```

Now, if I try and use the records returned from this query in another query, it takes 4 times or more longer to execute.
The simplest example I could think of to demonstrate this was the following:

```
select * into #temp
from  DLIFE.IS_TABLE_REPORT where [project_name] = 'myProject'
-- (82 row(s) affected) in 08:10
```

So for some reason, it 'appears' to be taking 6 minutes to write 82 rows into a temp table !?
Something more is happening here than I comprehend.

Looking at the Execution Plan & Statistics, there's a lot of difference between the two.
I had expected them to be pretty much the same !

Suddenly I realise how little I know.

Statistics:

Select

```
Table 'Key_Column_Definitions_Header'.  Scan count 0, logical reads 202
Table 'Worktable'.                      Scan count 2,952,361, logical reads 24,753,476;
Table 'DLIFE_Med_Short'.                Scan count 101, logical reads 41,496, read-ahead reads 1, 
Table 'DLIFE_IS_FD_RUN_HISTORY'.        Scan count 1, logical reads 88,
```

Select Into

```
Table 'Worktable'. Scan count 3825785, logical reads 29,257,307, physical reads 6,513; 
Table 'DLIFE_Med_Short'. Scan count 82, logical reads 40660, 
Table 'DLIFE_IS_FD_RUN_HISTORY'. Scan count 9, logical reads 182, 
Table 'Key_Column_Definitions_Header'. Scan count 1, logical reads 4, read-ahead reads 3,
```

Execution Plans

[image: Select]

[image: Select Into]

Comment: What happens when you use `SELECT ... INTO ... SELECT ... OPTION(MERGE JOIN)` ?

Comment: Not sure about the second select in your suggestion, but the following did seem to sort things:  select * into .. from DLIFE.IS_TABLE_REPORT where .. = .. OPTION(MERGE JOIN). So thank you very much :)   However, now I have the problem that you cannot include OPTION in a view definition. My view will be called by a 3rd party app that can only access tables/view by name. So close ... .!  Any ideas ?

Comment: Update:  So using OPTION(MERGE JOIN) resolved the above specific instance of my problem. However, I am now looking at another similar example and O(MJ) does not resolve the issue. I guess the root of this matter is in understanding WHY this situation arises. My new situation if very similar to above, a Query runs in 13 seconds on it's own. Yet if I try to do anything with the results (e.g: further calculations, insert into table) then QPlan changes and performance drops 3 or 4 fold.  Can anyone help throw further light on what is happening under the hood here ?

Comment: O(MJ) isn't the solution to all kind of performance problems. If there is another "similar" query with performance problems then follow the same steps: publish another question including the execution plans.